# Why does the Scala compiler give "value registerKryoClasses is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkConf" for Spark 1.4?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to register a class for Kryo as follows

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(...).setAppName(...)
conf.registerKryoClasses(Seq(classOf[MyClass]))
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

However, I get the following error

```
value registerKryoClasses is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

I also tried, `conf.registerKryoClasses(classOf[MyClass])`, but still it complains about the same error.

What mistake am I doing? I am using Spark 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `SparkConf.registerKryoClasses` is defined in Spark 1.4 (since 1.2). However, it expects an `Array[Class[_]]` as an argument. This might be the problem. Try calling `conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[MyClass]))` instead.

Comment: The kryo serializer is failing because of a List member variable of the class I'm trying to register. Does Kryo have problems with Java collections?

Comment: Kryo should be able to also serialize Java collections, if I remember correctly. But you also have to insert `conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")` into your Spark configuration to activate the Kryo serializers.

Comment: Yes I did so. It didn't work with List class, so I changed it to LinkedList. It worked that way. The reason it does not work with List class is perhaps because its immutable.